# How to create a VSIX template for .NET 6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I create a solution with 4 projects. One of them `VSIX project`, the other is `Project Template` and 2 of them are `Item template`. I want to create VSIX because all team use it. Exporting directly item template from visual studio working fine, but it is not good solution for team-works.

I use C# 10 version at my project. I want to create this template to targeting C# 10 language version. However in list there is only .NET Framework 4.8. So in this case, I cannot use record type or other new things.

How can I create a Visual Studio extension for .NET 6? How I target that or is there another way?

I use Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 targets .NET Framework, so you cannot write a VSIX targeting .NET 6 and have it install into VS2022.

That said, if you want to use newer C# features in .NET Framework projects, you can create an SDK-style project and manually change the `.csproj` file to have `TargetFramework` `net472` and set `LangVersion` to `10` or whatever you prefer. While this works, it's not a scenario that Microsoft supports.

Note that for VSIX projects this is currently a bit tricky to get working. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/3742e229b41a086d738745a5e5a7a15f535deff7/setup/ProjectSystemSetup/ProjectSystemSetup.csproj), however that's quite a complex build so it will require a good level of familiarity with MSBuild to use it as a reference.

Once you have increase the language version, you will also need something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/IsExternalInit to make record types compile correctly for .NET Framework.

Comment: I handle this another way but it is not good solution. I export my multi-file item template and add an zip assert to vsix project. In this case, item template files are not a part of project.